# Automatic reference counting in xcode4.2 for iphone 5 was conflicted with __bridge

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I want to create a simple project to study ios5.0 programing on xcode4.2. this is the original code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"win" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( ( CFURLRef)url, &winSoundID);
```

compile error:

> file://localhost/Users/Hikari/Documents/Projects/Pickers/Pickers/CustomPickerViewController.m:
>   error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Cast to 'CFURLRef' (aka
>   'const struct __CFURL *') of an Objective-C pointer to a
>   non-Objective-C pointer is disallowed with Automatic Reference
>   Counting

So I have searched for it on google, some friends say that I must add macro '__bridge' to solve it but that doesn't work.

code:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( ( __bridge CFURLRef)url, &winSoundID);
```

error:

> file://localhost/Users/Hikari/Documents/Projects/Pickers/Pickers/CustomPickerViewController.m:
>   error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier '__bridge'

Automatic Reference Counting is Enable!
   how to solve this problem???

Comment: iOS 5.0 is still under NDA; can't talk about that specifically.

Comment: While ARC is no longer under Apple's NDA, iOS 5 still is. Any answerers who are subject to Apple's NDA should be aware of that and consider whether you can answer this without violating your agreement.

Answer (score 1):

objc_unretainedPointer
the answer is that.
code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"win" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( (CFURLRef)objc_unretainedPointer(url), &winSoundID);

path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"crunch" ofType:@"wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)objc_unretainedPointer([NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]), &crunchSoundID);
```

### it works fine.

ps: thanks Macmade to help me edit the codes.I think i've learned how.

Comment: You shouldn't need this. There is something wrong....

Answer (score 1):

try ur Project Setting, type "automatic reference", and set the Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to NO, disable it and recompile u will still get warning message but it does compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are compiling that file with ARC *always*.   That looks more like the file is compiled once with ARC enabled, giving you the first error, and a second time with ARC disabled, giving you the second error once you fix the first.